# asp.net update database from drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, sql-update

I'm trying to allow a user select their marital status that will update a field in a database.  This is fine when it is the user's first time, but if they want to update it again, it will not update.

If I choose a data source, if they wish to update, they aren't given any other options in the DDL other that what was selected the first time.

**ASPX********

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLMarital" runat="server" TabIndex="1">
                <asp:ListItem Value = "Single" Text = "Single">Single</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value = "Married" Text = "Married">Married</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value = "Separated" Text = "Separated">Separated</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value = "Divorced" Text = "Divorced">Divorced</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

*******ASPX.VB************

```
'binding...
```

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    Dim dvSql4 As DataView =
DirectCast(SqlMarital.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
    For Each drvSql4 As DataRowView In dvSql4
        DDLMarital.Text = drvSql4("Marital_Status").ToString()
    Next
```

End Sub

'updating the database when the "Next" button is clicked
Protected Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\scrummingit2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Student_Personal_Details SET Marital_Status = @Marital WHERE Student_No = @StudentNo")

    Dim maritalParam As New SqlParameter("@Marital", DDLMarital.Text)
    Dim studentNoParam As New SqlParameter("@StudentNo", lblEnrolmentStudentNumber.Text)

    lblEnrolmentStudentNumber.Text = Session("Student")

    cmd.Parameters.Add(maritalParam)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(studentNoParam)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
```

End Sub

Can anyone help? Getting desperate now after days of not finding any answers on Google.

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: no errors.  just continues as expected apart from the database not updating

Comment: you can check with sql-profiler what is being pass when you execute query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for a PostBack, and assign the selected value only if it is not a PostBack.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If Not IsPostBack
        Dim dvSql4 As DataView =
    DirectCast(SqlMarital.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        For Each drvSql4 As DataRowView In dvSql4
            DDLMarital.Text = drvSql4("Marital_Status").ToString()
        Next
   End If
End Sub
```

The user's selection is at present being ignored as the value get reset on every `Load`

Comment: thanks @nunespascal!  it works perfectly! little bit less stressed now.